# Is it possible for theory with both ${\phi}^{3}$ and ${\phi}^{4}$ interaction terms, giving zero two-to-two elastic scattering amplitude?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

Is it possible for theory with both ${\phi}^{3}$ and ${\phi}^{4}$ interaction terms, giving 0 two-to-two elastic scattering up to second order in scalar theory?
I was wondering if we could choose the coupling constants $g_3$ and $g_4$ associated with the two terms so that their contribution to second order vanishes. These two terms can be introduces by mere redefinition of field in free scalar theory and therefore the scattering amplitude should be zero for certain choice of constants and mass. I just want to know whether it should be possible or makes sense at all?

Answer (score 2):

1. It is enough to consider the connected 4-point tree amplitude ${\cal A}^{c,{\rm tree}}_4$ in momentum space. It consists of 4 diagrams: $\times$ and the $s$,$t$,$u$-channel of $>\!\!\!-\!\!\!<$.

   The combination can generically not vanish (except if $g_3=0=g_4$) because each of the 4 diagram carry different momentum dependence. This remains true when we impose the momentum conservation from  elastic scattering, i.e. when the 4 momenta are 2 pairs of opposite momenta.
2. The (not necessarily connected) 4-point tree amplitude ${\cal A}^{\rm tree}_4$ has 3 more diagrams: The $s$,$t$,$u$-channel of $||$.

   So even in the free theory ${\cal A}_4={\cal A}^{\rm tree}_4+{\cal O}(\hbar)$ is non-zero (in the same way that $S={\bf 1}+iT$ contain disconnected contributions).
3. Under a field redefinition of a free theory, besides generating $\phi^3$ and $\phi^4$ terms, one would typically also generate derivative couplings, and it could be quite challenging to see perturbatively that it is just a free theory in disguise.

Comment: Hello @Qmechanic, 
1. How can the scattering amplitude be non-zero in a free theory? I think only connected diagrams contribute to scattering amplitude. 2. Also, the scattering amplitude described by Feynman diagrams should always describe elastic scattering because of energy/momentum conservation in vertices, so I don't get your remark about the restriction to elastic scattering.

Comment: I updated the answer.